# Error in Android --Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo

Tags: android, instrumentation

For Example I had an application that will invoke contacts and has to select one of the contact. 
But its not doing exactly what I want. It is showing me error `Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.sample/com.sample.ContactsSelectInstrumentation}`

Following is my Code..
This is my Activity class

```
 @Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
button.setOnClickListener(mGoListener);
}
private OnClickListener mGoListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  startInstrumentation(new ComponentName(Test.this,
      ContactsFilterInstrumentation.class), null, null);
}
};
```

And this is my Intrumentation class.

```
class ContactsFilterInstrumentation extends Instrumentation {  
@Override    
  public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {

super.onCreate(arguments);
start(); 

} 

 @Override  

public void onStart() {

super.onStart();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClassName(getTargetContext(), "com.android.phone.Dialer");
Activity activity = startActivitySync(intent);

Log.i("ContactsFilterInstrumentation", "Started: " + activity);
sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_M));
sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_M));
sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A));
sendKeySync(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A));
waitForIdleSync();
Log.i("ContactsFilterInstrumentation", "Done!");
finish(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
}
}
```

Can Any help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory structure should be:

```
src
  package.x.y.z.test
      MainTest.java
      CustomInstrumentationRunner.java
```

Then in the AndroidManifest.xml, set

```
<manifest package="package.x.y.z" ...

<instrumentation
        android:name="package.x.y.z.test.CustomInstrumentationRunner"
```

Invoke the above package with the command line:

```
adb shell am instrumentation -w package.x.y.z/package.x.y.z.test.CustomInstrumentationRunner
```

Answer (score 1):

An Instrumentation implementation is described to the system through an AndroidManifest.xml's `<instrumentation>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

1. Use a upper-level package name in the manifest:
2. Implement the test packages one level down:
   Java file 1:

   package com.xxx.yyy.zzz.ptest.onlylogin;

Java file 2:

```
package com.xxx.yyy.zzz.ptest.register;
```

1. Specify the command line like the following:

   ...