# Robotium from command line on Mac

Tags: android, robotium

I'm testing Android application, and I want to run Robotium test from Terminal on Mac. As I've read I use `adb shell am instrument -w com.test.test1/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`
Terminal says "-bash: adb: command not found".
Probably, I don't see something obvious, but I'm really just studying. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have your Environment Variables set properly. You need to cd into the directory of your android sdk and then go to platform-tools folder. Once you are in there you will be able to use adb.

here is more information (Goto the part where it talks about environment variables in "Exploring the SDK section"

On Linux, edit your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc file. Look for a line that sets the PATH environment variable and add the full path to the tools/ and platform-tools/ directories to it. If you don't see a line setting the path, you can add one:
export PATH=${PATH}:/tools:/platform-tools

On a Mac OS X, look in your home directory for .bash_profile and proceed as for Linux. You can create the .bash_profile if you don't already have one.

Comment: Thanks! That's progress, but now it says 'INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.test.test1/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.test.test1/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608914/error-in-android-unable-to-find-instrumentation-info-for-componentinfo